# Blazor project builds locally but not in azure pipeline

Tags: c#, azure, swagger, blazor, cicd

I have a blazor server project using .net 5. I am able to run it fine locally and connect to my API.  In my local project I have a swaggerClient and swagger.json file. In startup I call

```
swaggerClient swagclient = new swaggerClient(Constants.baseAddress, httpClient2);
```

Everything works fine locally, even if I deploy to IIS again works fine.  I am now setting up pipeline in azure for CI/CD and have a dotnet core template to build my project.  Anyways when it comes time to build in azure I have about 100+ plus errors that are all referencing classes that exist in my swaggerClient and Cannot find the file. For example:

/home/vsts/work/9/s/obj/Release/netcoreapp3.1/RazorDeclaration/Pages/Index.razor.g.cs(2952,75): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'swaggerClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/vsts/work/9/s/FDI.csproj]

Anyways i'm not sure if i'm setting up the pipeline correctly or if there is any additional configuration I need to do to get this to work, i've been looking all over thanks.

Also I was referencing how Tim Corey connects to an API in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nY-w9wPFEuY&ab_channel=IAmTimCorey

Answer (score 1):

Looks like dev ops didn't have the reference to the swagger file in my project file and wasn't  properly detecting changes, so it was never checked in properly.